# Unable to install angular-cli on Windows 7 (using npm)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have Windows 7 32 bit on my machine
and Visual Studio Code, VSCodium

my Node version is 13.13.0 (since I couldn't find a more recent one that works on my OS)

upon running the following command in VSCode, VSCodium I ran through the following errors/warnings:

```
PS C:\Users\user\Documents\VS Code\angular> npm install -g '@angular/cli'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng.js
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @angular/cli@17.2.3: wanted: {"node":"^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0","npm":"^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 || >=8.0.0","yarn":">= 1.13.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @angular/cli@17.2.3
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for ini@4.1.1: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: ini@4.1.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for inquirer@9.2.14: wanted: {"node":">=18"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: inquirer@9.2.14
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for npm-package-arg@11.0.1: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm-package-arg@11.0.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @angular-devkit/architect@0.1702.3: wanted: {"node":"^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0","npm":"^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 || >=8.0.0","yarn":">= 1.13.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @angular-devkit/architect@0.1702.3
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @angular-devkit/core@17.2.3: wanted: {"node":"^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0","npm":"^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 || >=8.0.0","yarn":">= 1.13.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @angular-devkit/core@17.2.3
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for npm-pick-manifest@9.0.0: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm-pick-manifest@9.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @schematics/angular@17.2.3: wanted: {"node":"^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0","npm":"^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 || >=8.0.0","yarn":">= 1.13.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @schematics/angular@17.2.3
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @angular-devkit/schematics@17.2.3: wanted: {"node":"^18.13.0 || >=20.9.0","npm":"^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 || >=8.0.0","yarn":">= 1.13.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @angular-devkit/schematics@17.2.3
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for pacote@17.0.6: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: pacote@17.0.6
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for chalk@5.3.0: wanted: {"node":"^12.17.0 || ^14.13 || >=16.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: chalk@5.3.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for mute-stream@1.0.0: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: mute-stream@1.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for validate-npm-package-name@5.0.0: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: validate-npm-package-name@5.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for hosted-git-info@7.0.1: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: hosted-git-info@7.0.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for proc-log@3.0.0: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: proc-log@3.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for lru-cache@10.2.0: wanted: {"node":"14 || >=16.14"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: lru-cache@10.2.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for npm-install-checks@6.3.0: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm-install-checks@6.3.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for npm-normalize-package-bin@3.0.1: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm-normalize-package-bin@3.0.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @npmcli/promise-spawn@7.0.1: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @npmcli/promise-spawn@7.0.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for minipass@7.0.4: wanted: {"node":">=16 || 14 >=14.17"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: minipass@7.0.4
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for npm-registry-fetch@16.1.0: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm-registry-fetch@16.1.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for cacache@18.0.2: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: cacache@18.0.2
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for npm-packlist@8.0.2: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm-packlist@8.0.2
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for fs-minipass@3.0.3: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: fs-minipass@3.0.3
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @npmcli/run-script@7.0.4: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @npmcli/run-script@7.0.4
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @npmcli/installed-package-contents@2.0.2: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @npmcli/installed-package-contents@2.0.2
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for read-package-json@7.0.0: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: read-package-json@7.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @npmcli/git@5.0.4: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @npmcli/git@5.0.4
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for read-package-json-fast@3.0.2: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: read-package-json-fast@3.0.2
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for sigstore@2.2.2: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: sigstore@2.2.2
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for ssri@10.0.5: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: ssri@10.0.5
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for which@4.0.0: wanted: {"node":"^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: which@4.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for isexe@3.1.1: wanted: {"node":">=16"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: isexe@3.1.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for npm-bundled@3.0.0: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm-bundled@3.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @npmcli/package-json@5.0.0: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @npmcli/package-json@5.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for node-gyp@10.0.1: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: node-gyp@10.0.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @npmcli/node-gyp@3.0.0: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @npmcli/node-gyp@3.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for normalize-package-data@6.0.0: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: normalize-package-data@6.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for glob@10.3.10: wanted: {"node":">=16 || 14 >=14.17"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: glob@10.3.10
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for json-parse-even-better-errors@3.0.1: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: json-parse-even-better-errors@3.0.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for path-scurry@1.10.1: wanted: {"node":">=16 || 14 >=14.17"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: path-scurry@1.10.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for foreground-child@3.1.1: wanted: {"node":">=14"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: foreground-child@3.1.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for minimatch@9.0.3: wanted: {"node":">=16 || 14 >=14.17"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: minimatch@9.0.3
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for jackspeak@2.3.6: wanted: {"node":">=14"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: jackspeak@2.3.6
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for signal-exit@4.1.0: wanted: {"node":">=14"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: signal-exit@4.1.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @pkgjs/parseargs@0.11.0: wanted: {"node":">=14"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @pkgjs/parseargs@0.11.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for make-fetch-happen@13.0.0: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: make-fetch-happen@13.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for nopt@7.2.0: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: nopt@7.2.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for minipass-fetch@3.0.4: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: minipass-fetch@3.0.4
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @npmcli/agent@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @npmcli/agent@2.2.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for http-proxy-agent@7.0.2: wanted: {"node":">= 14"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: http-proxy-agent@7.0.2
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for socks-proxy-agent@8.0.2: wanted: {"node":">= 14"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: socks-proxy-agent@8.0.2
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for agent-base@7.1.0: wanted: {"node":">= 14"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: agent-base@7.1.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for https-proxy-agent@7.0.4: wanted: {"node":">= 14"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: https-proxy-agent@7.0.4
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for unique-filename@3.0.0: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: unique-filename@3.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @npmcli/fs@3.1.0: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @npmcli/fs@3.1.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for minipass-collect@2.0.1: wanted: {"node":">=16 || 14 >=14.17"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: minipass-collect@2.0.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for unique-slug@4.0.0: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: unique-slug@4.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for abbrev@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: abbrev@2.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for ignore-walk@6.0.4: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: ignore-walk@6.0.4
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @sigstore/tuf@2.3.1: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @sigstore/tuf@2.3.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @sigstore/verify@1.1.0: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @sigstore/verify@1.1.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @sigstore/sign@2.2.3: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @sigstore/sign@2.2.3
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @sigstore/core@1.0.0: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @sigstore/core@1.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @sigstore/bundle@2.2.0: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @sigstore/bundle@2.2.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @sigstore/protobuf-specs@0.3.0: wanted: {"node":"^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @sigstore/protobuf-specs@0.3.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for tuf-js@2.2.0: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: tuf-js@2.2.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @tufjs/models@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @tufjs/models@2.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @tufjs/canonical-json@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":"^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.13.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @tufjs/canonical-json@2.0.0

+ @angular/cli@17.2.3
added 74 packages from 28 contributors, removed 44 packages and updated 63 packages in 275.604s
```

PS C:\Users\user\Documents\VS Code\angular> ng new

**The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**>

I've tried both VSCode and VSCodium and I also tried specifying a specific version of angular. but nothing seems to help.

Any clue what should I do :(

**Edited**
I know the problem relies in the fact that I'm using an old Operating System; to begin with.

Had I been able to upgrade my OS, I would have done so already.

But I do hope there's some workaround that could perhaps solve my issue.

Comment: you should use `npm install -g @angular/cli` try to remove the string or quotes on `'@angular/cli'`

Comment: I used the quotes since I'm getting: Unrecognized token in source text.
At line:1 char:16
Upon searching for this error, someone suggested the quote solution which seems to work

Comment: If you want to create a new Angular project, for time being, you can try with `npx ng new <PROJECT_NAME>`

Comment: The NodeJS LTS version is supported by Windows 32 bit. What does `since I couldn't find a more recent one that works on my OS` even means? What kind of error did you have? By the logs you posted you have to update NodeJS. So - to me - the problem relies on that update.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Obviously I have tried several versions of node before finding that the last one which worked on my OS is 13.3 (When I run the setup I'm getting this error **_This application is only supported on Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2 or higher_**)

Comment: @Claies I'm actually trying to learn angular, so forgive me for using such an old machine (this is what I have got) I' would have appreciated a more useful comment which actually helps out

Comment: @Ｒの卄ＩＴupon running your suggestion, I got the following error: 
**npx: installed 1 in 17.459s
command not found: ng**

Comment: It seems you are resistant to upgrading your OS, but please reconsider. Being on an older OS will hinder your ability to learn for many reasons. Does your hardware support a newer OS? If so, I recommend even installing a trial version of a newer Windows OS. If upgrading Windows is not possible, then consider using linux.

Comment: The thing is, Microsoft ended support for Windows 7 on January 14, 2020.  That's 4 years ago.  "This is what I have got" is not going to change the fact that it is just too old to run any of the newer toolsets.

Comment: @Geo242 it's not that I'm resistant but unfortunately  I've restrictions of doing so on this particular PC. I will consider having a dual-boot linux if no one else could help :(    To be frank, I was hoping that with the expertise of this community -where I'm used to always finding a solution- that I might actually find one

Answer (score 0):

Considering [this](https://angular.io/guide/versions) latest Angular version you can use is 13.3.x. So to use `ng` commands you need instal it globally `npm install -g @angular/cli@13.3`. Just keep in mind, that this version of angular is not supported already, so I'd reccomend to update your OS to be able to use latest versions of angular. Especially considerind that angular team advice to use standalone components since v15 and signals since v17.

Comment: Sorry dear, it didn't work as well. The same errors/warnings but with different versions for the dependent packages  :(

Comment: show the error please

Comment: I had to cut out most of it coz comments are limited
these packages want: {"node":"^12.13.0||^14.15.0||>=16.0.0"} others want (12.20||14.15)
@angular/cli@13.3.11
@schematics/angular@13.3.11
@angular-devkit/schematics@13.3.11
@angular-devkit/core@13.3.11
@angular-devkit/architect@0.1303.11
pacote@12.0.3
npm-registry-fetch@12.0.2
npmlog@6.0.2
are-we-there-yet@3.0.1
gauge@4.0.4
make-fetch-happen@10.2.1
cacache@16.1.3
minipass-fetch@2.1.2
ssri@9.0.1
@npmcli/fs@2.1.2
@npmcli/move-file@2.0.1
unique-filename@2.0.1
unique-slug@3.0.0

Comment: oh, right, you need node 12 for that, not 13. use nvm to manage node version or just uninstals existing ones and instal ^12.13 ones

Comment: Upon exploring the folder where node_modules were located I found the angular folder and cli within it, the bin folder had an ng file.

Comment: Apparently my environment path can't see it even though I added its path myself. Could it be coz of the @ symbol in the path. Returning to my initial question I think that ng was installed successfully at that time ** 
+ @angular/cli@17.2.3** now the question is what should I do for vscode to run ng command?

Comment: ng command should work in any terminal, not only VSCode it f it is installed. But angular 17 won;t work with your version of node. if you have angular v17 and node 12 or 13 it won't work for you. Just uninstall angular cli globally and install compatible version

Comment: Yes dear, I have tried ng command after I followed your advice (uninstalled 13.13.0 & installed node 12.14.1, I managed to run `node ng new myapp` in cmd prompt -I changed directory to the bin folder- but it didn't work in vscode, I'm not sure why (since I added its path to environment variable PATH) I have a feeling it's the @ which exists in the path, I shall experiment more to try to solve it. Thanks alot for your help :)

Comment: it is possible, some spesial characters may cause problems because commands may consider it as part of the command, not just a string. I never had problem with `@` because I rarely use it, but I remember I had issue with `nvm` because of the whitespace character used in my machine username.